# How to download a file to KnownFolder using BackroundTransfer?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm testing [BackgroundTransfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ152726(v=win.10).aspx) on Windows Phone 8.1 RT and I'm facing strange issue, when I try to download a file to one of the *KnownFolders*.

The code is as follow:

```cs
string address = @"http://www.onereason.org/archive/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/universe.jpg";
StorageFile tempFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("temp.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
BackgroundDownloader manager = new BackgroundDownloader();
var operation = manager.CreateDownload(new Uri(address), tempFile);
IProgress<DownloadOperation> progressH = new Progress<DownloadOperation>((p) =>
{ Debug.WriteLine("Transferred: {0}, Total: {1}", p.Progress.BytesReceived, p.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive); });
await operation.StartAsync().AsTask(progressH);
Debug.WriteLine("BacgroundTransfer created");
```

It's quite simple and **works** if I download to *ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder*, but if I do it like above, the transfer never completes, though the progresshandler says all bytes have been received:

[image: transferred]

The code never reaches the line `Debug.WriteLine("BacgroundTransfer created");` and if I take a look at proccesses on the phone, I can see that *RuntimeBroker* is using the CPU at 100%:

[image: runtimebroker]

obviously it's also continuing its work after you finish debugging the app and the phone becomes hotter and hotter. The fastest way to cancel this situation is to uninstall the app, as with this action all corresponding background transfers are cancelled.

All the necessary capabilieties are being set. I can for example download the file to *LocalFolder* and then copy to *KnownFolder*, but it's additional redundant action. Is there a way to download a file directly to *KnownFolder*? Have I missed something?

Comment: Is the pictures library in an SD card? And  does it repro 100% times?

Comment: @kiewic Yes it's on SD card, but all capabilities are set, I can download to localfolder and copy to PicturesLibrary. And yes - it happenes every single time.